# How to use -filter_complex and -vf in same command in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I edit the video with the command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -y -vf eq=saturation={rand_saturation},fade=in:st=0:d={rand_fade},hflip,noise=alls={rand_noise}:allf=t -c:a copy output.mp4
```

then the resulting video

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),1,W-w-10)':y='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),5,H-h-200)'" -c:a copy output_1.mp4
```

I tried to combine all this together so that I didn't have to spend time processing the video twice, but I couldn't do it because you can't use the -vf and -filter_complex commands together. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First apply the video specific filters before using the result as overlay input.

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]eq=saturation={rand_saturation},fade=in:st=0:d={rand_fade},hflip,noise=alls={rand_noise}:allf=t[vid];[vid][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),1,W-w-10)':y='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),5,H-h-200)'" -c:a copy output_1.mp4`